# How to pass Query String Parameters in GET url using Rest Assured?

Tags: api, automated-tests, restful-architecture, rest-assured, web-api-testing

How to pass Query String Parameters in GET url using Rest Assured?

URL is: `http://example.com/building`

My Query Strings are :

```
globalDates:{"startMs":1473672973818,"endMs":1481448973817,"period":90}
limitTo:6
loadTvData:true
startFrom:0
userId:5834fb36981baacb6a876427
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass them as a queryParam ..

```
given()
.queryParam("globalDates", "{\"startMs\":1473672973818,\"endMs\":1481448973817,\"period\":90}")
.queryParam("startFrom", "0").queryParam("limitTo", "6").queryParam("loadTvData", true)
.queryParam("startFrom", "0").queryParam("userId", "5834fb36981baacb6a876427")
.when().get("http://example.com/building"). ...
```

Answer (score 7):

And also you can put this queryparams in Map like follows,

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() {{

put("globalDates", "{\"startMs\":1473672973818,\"endMs\":1481448973817,\"period\":90}");

put("limitTo","6" );

,...

}}
```

And post it like follows,

```
 resp = RestAssured.given()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .queryParameters(params)
                    .post(apiURL).andReturn();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, just what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
QueryParam can be passed as:

String endpoint = "http://example.com/building"; 

var response = given()
.queryParam("globalDates", "{\"startMs\":1473672973818,\"endMs\":1481448973817,\"period\":90}")
.queryParam("startFrom", "0").queryParam("limitTo", "6").queryParam("loadTvData", true)
.queryParam("startFrom", "0").queryParam("userId", "5834fb36981baacb6a876427")
.when().get(endpoint).then();
```

Answer (score 0):

For our api with a type like this:

https://my.api.com/meeting?page=0&size=1

We have:

```
Response response = requestSpecification.queryParam("page", 0).queryParam("size", 1).get(baseEndpoint);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass query string parameters in a GET URL using Rest Assured like this :

```
when()
  .parameter("globalDates","startMs","1474260058054","endMs","1482036058051","period","90")                              
  .parameters("limitTo","6")                                  
  .parameters("loadTvData","true")                                
  .parameters("startFrom","0")
  .parameters("userId","5834fb36981baacb6a876427");
```

Comment: The `parameter()` and `parameters()` methods are currently deprecated.